# Set type of object while uploading to google cloud storage using java library

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Using Java library to uploading the object to GCP https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample with the below code

```
public static void uploadObject(
      String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName, String filePath) throws IOException {
    
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
    storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));

    System.out.println(
        "File " + filePath + " uploaded to bucket " + bucketName + " as " + objectName);
  }
```

The above code works well, but the content type of the image is `application/octet-stream`
How do I set to `image/jpg` or `image/png`. How can I set the meta-data before uploading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BlobInfo` has a `Builder` which has a lot of options including `setContentType`.

https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/BlobInfo.Builder.html

If you always see builder/newBuilder, you need to investigate the documentation further to see if there are other (setters).

```
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("image/jpeg").build();
```

=== Edited ===

```
public String determineContentType(File inputFile){

   String contentType =  // Your logic of determining type of file format

  return contentType;

}

    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(determineContentType(yourFile)).build();
```

Comment: How can set dynamically. The file may be PNG or JPG or JPEG

Comment: If else?  It depends on how you define what is a PNG, what is a JPEG?

Comment: Thanks, can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66577896/uploaded-object-public-url-is-download-link-after-uploading-the-object-to-gcp-us