# Uploaded object Public URL is download link after uploading the object to GCP using java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have successfully uploaded the object to the google cloud storage using the Java library code as below

```
public static void uploadObject(
      String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName, String filePath) throws IOException {
    
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
    storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));

    System.out.println(
        "File " + filePath + " uploaded to bucket " + bucketName + " as " + objectName);
  }
```

[image]

If I browse the public URL

If I browse the URL https://storage.googleapis.com/fetebird-product/bird.jpg the file is the downloadable link. How can I make it just a simple browsing file

What I am missing?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by simple browsing file?  When clicking on bird.jpg I was able to download it.  What do you want to do?

Comment: I should not download, it should open in the browser, because I need map all this URL to img src and when people browse the image it should view in browser instead of downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer from Googling/StackOverflow, which states:

[How do I force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf)

> To indicate to the browser that the file should be viewed in the
> browser, the HTTP response should include these headers:

**Content-Type: application/pdf Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"**

> To have the file downloaded rather than viewed:

**Content-Type: application/pdf Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"**

> The quotes around the filename are required if the filename contains
> special characters such as filename[1].pdf which may otherwise break
> the browser's ability to handle the response.
>
> How you set the HTTP response headers will depend on your HTTP server
> (or, if you are generating the PDF response from server-side code:
> your server-side programming language).

Therefore, in your logic you need to do:

```
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("image/jpeg").setContentDisposition(String.format("inline; filename=\"%s\"", yourPictureFileName)).build();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, can you ask you one more favor. How do I get just uploaded  image public URL in java library. From the documentation I can see https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME for public URL. But is there any way I can get this URL in java code after uploading the image

Comment: @SanJaisy hmm not sure.  Cant you just construct it yourself?  

https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket.name}/{blob.name}  If you already know the bucket name? and you know the file name....then its a String concaternation

Comment: @SanJaisy  try Blob b = storage.create(xxxxxxx);   b.getMetaData() <-- This returns a hashmap of key/value...see if the URL is 1 of them :) good luck